# create thumbnails using for loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, thumbnails

How to create Thumbnails from an unzipped image folder using for loop in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 1):

nope
this would be better

```
config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width'] = 100;
$config['height'] = 100;
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
foreach ($images AS $file) {
    $config['source_image'] = $file;
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the directory helper:

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
```

Map the directory:

```
$images = directory_map('./directoryRelativeToIndexDotPhp/');
```

Now you an array of files in $images, set up a configure array for the image_lib class and loop through them, resizing the images:

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width'] = 100;
$config['height'] = 100;
foreach ($images AS $file) {
    $config['source_image'] = $file;
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

Not tested but this should give you a good start. You will probably want to check if the files are actually images before resizing.

Check out the documentation on the image manipulation library http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html